# how to call index.php as the default, but only for a specific domain?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a few sites hosted on the same server,
but there is only one htaccess file that i guess governs all of them.
so how can i make index.php the default instead of index.html for only one of these sites?

thanks!

```
# -FrontPage-


IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*


<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
AuthName site1.com
AuthUserFile /home/myuser/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.pwd
AuthGroupFile /home/myuser/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.grp
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
AddHandler server-parsed .html

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site1\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site1.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.html)?$ /index.php [L,NC]`
```

Comment: Have you done any effort or do you expect us to do all the work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any particular site `www.site.com` have this rule in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.html)?$ /index.php [L,NC]
```

#### Suggested `.htaccess`:

```
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site1\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site1.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.html)?$ /index.php [L,NC]

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
AuthName site1.com
AuthUserFile /home/myuser/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.pwd
AuthGroupFile /home/myuser/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.grp
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
AddHandler server-parsed .html
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to work, maybe because of the previous rule that I have already set? also, what if i want it to work both for www.site.com and site.com?  

thanks  

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site1\.com  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site1.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site2\.com$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(index\.html)?$ /index.php [L,NC]`

Comment: `This rule already works for both www.site.com and site.com`. Can you post your complete .htaccess in your question?

Comment: ok, how do I insert here a linebreak in the code?  the double space doesn't seem to do anything :/

Comment: Don't put code in comments. Edit your question and post the code.

Comment: FOr which URL it didn't work? Did you get 404 or got `index.html` shown?

Comment: I have tested this rule many times and always found `index.php` being server. Q1. Is this the only .htaccess or do you have another? Q2. Is that the only code in this .htaccess? If you have some other code (not shown here)then please post it in question? Q3. What is location of above .htaccess?

Comment: Q1. it's the only one as far as i can see.
Q2. yes that's the whole code.
Q3. the location is the /public_html/ folder, and the files of site1.com are kept in it, site2.com is an addon domain and has a folder with the location /public_html/site2.com/ which does not have an .htaccess file. maybe the problem is that it is an addon domain?

Comment: Is `site2.com` is an addon domain then above rule isn't even being run. You need to place my suggested rule from top to `/public_html/site2.com/.htaccess`